# Debugging Cordova on Mobile

Tags: android, html, mobile, cordova, remote-debugging

I'm building a HTML5 Game and deploying it to my Android phone for testing using Apache Cordova.

Is there anyway to debug my application on the device while it's running, such as seeing the JS Console?

Comment: [Debugging in PhoneGap · phonegap/phonegap Wiki](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/wiki/Debugging-in-PhoneGap)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you taken a look at the [debug.phonegap.com](http://debug.phonegap.com/)?

Another way you can upload the html to a server or localhost and use it. But this only for outside the apk:

https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging

Comment: Will it work with Cordova though? Because Cordova compiles a APK containing a Web View and the HTML App that is then deployed to the phone. It's not a HTML page that I'm viewing through a mobile browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can also [run your Cordova project](http://docs.appgyver.com/tooling/cli/usage-with-cordova/) via the [AppGyver Steroids](http://www.appgyver.com/steroids/) tooling, which gives you enhanced access to the Safari and Chrome web inspectors.